# Page content falls over footer Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

I really need your help.

I faced problem when I add widgets such as ninja form or tab responsive into my page they falls over on footer.

Page suppose to expand body for content but it expand footer for that purpose. Unfortunately website is in Russian but I think you can see what’s going on.

In page source it shows that #content take height: 755px; when I try to modify it in style.css.

I does not make changes. When I set auto I works but not permanently.

http://zumrf.ru/oformim_zakaz/

Comment: Maybe include some code so we can work out your issue easier. Until I see what properties are affecting what

Comment: Try after removing height from #content.

Comment: Add `float: none;` on `line#2050`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `#footer` `clear: both;` in your CSS and it's fixed.
Your `#primary` has a float, that's why the content is over your footer.

Comment: My friend, i appreciate your answer. It works. Could you explain more why it was like that.  Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css and try.

```
#content{min-height: 530px; overflow: visible;}

#colophon { clear: both;}
```

remove  from #content

```
height: 530px;
```